# HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject() causes exception in Silverlight 4 User control

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I get an exception in VS2010 designer when I use user control with code which contains
HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject() method. I've tried to move that code from control constructor to other methods but it doesn't help. I am using Silverliht 4.

Now I call HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject("MainPage", this) in UserControl_Loaded handler.

The exception message is

> at
>   System.Windows.Browser.ManagedObject.CreateHandle()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Browser.ManagedObject.GetObjectHandleAddRef()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject(String
>   scriptKey, Object instance, Boolean
>   isRestricted)    at
>   System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.RegisterScriptableObject(String
>   scriptKey, Object instance)    at
>   SL_Form.forms.VT_kv_2010.UserControl_Loaded(Object
>   sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in
>   C:\SL2\SL_Form\forms\1VT_kv.xaml.cs:line
>   1533    at
>   MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32
>   typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate,
>   Object sender, Object args)    at
>   MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr
>   unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs,
>   Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32
>   actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)

I can't use designer due to this bag. Although project builds without any errors and works fine. Any help will be appreciated.

John Smith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you just put it inside an if not designer mode?  that's (afaik) the typical approach for situations like this.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.isindesignmode%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you, it's solved the problem. I've looked in a bunch of Silverlight books but none of them mentioned that approach.